# Is there a name for complement of recursively enumerable set?

Tags: terminology, computability, undecidability

If there is a recursive function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x \notin A$}\\
\text{undefined} & \text{if $x \in A$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Is there a special name for the class of sets like $A$?

Comment: co-Recursively Enumerable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_%28complexity%29

Comment: @HuckBennett Why not make that an answer?

Comment: Thanks for migrating! I didn't know that this site existed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complement of a recursively enumerable (RE) language is called [co-recursively enumerable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RE_%28complexity%29) (co-RE).

As RE and co-RE form the first level of the [arithmetic hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_hierarchy), they are also known by aliases $\Sigma_1^0$ and $\Pi_1^0$.

Comment: Generally, for any complexity class $\mathcal{C}$, we usually denote the complement by $\mathrm{co}\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Or co-c.e. C.e. = computably enumerable. Generally the word "computable" is supplanting the word "recursive", at least within mathematics.